# Silverlight color resources using A="" R="" G="" B="" cause exception in app

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight, xaml, expression-blend

When defining a color resource in a Silverlight app using the syntax A="" R="" G="" B="" (any order of parameters) an exception is caused, even though the application will compile fine and display properly in Blend.

Example:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <Color x:Key="BlackBG" A="255" R="35" G="35" B="35"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The error reported if using an HTML Object tag to display the Silverlight control will be

> Unhandled Error in Silverlight 2 Application 
>   Code: 2103
>   Category: InitializeError
>   Message: Invalid or malformed application: Check manifest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using the A="" R="" G="" B="" syntax, e.g.

```
<Color x:Key="BlackBG" A="255" R="35" G="35" B="35"/>
```

Use the alternate syntax

```
<Color x:Key="BlackBG">#FF252525</Color>
```

Comment: Someone know why we cannot use ARGB syntax?